# Calculate $\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^x+x^{2x}+x^{3x}+...\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Calculate:
> $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^x+x^{2x}+x^{3x}+...+x^{nx}\right), n \in\mathbb{N_{\geq 1}}$$

If I have $x^x$ as my first case, then I get $$\frac{d}{dy}x^x=x^x\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)$$ Likewise, for $n=2$ I get: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^x+x^{2x}\right)=x^x\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)+2x^{2x}\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)$$
For $n=3$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^x+x^{2x}+x^{3x}\right)=x^x\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)+2x^{2x}\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)+3x^{3x}\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)$$

If I keep following this logic, I can see that for the last $n$, I get:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^x+x^{2x}+x^{3x}+...+x^{nx}\right)=x^x\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)+2x^{2x}\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)+3x^{3x}\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right) + ...+nx^{nx}(\ln(x)+1)$$

I can then use induction to prove this. However, if instead of the function being finite, what if it was infinite? How would I find:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^x+x^{2x}+x^{3x}+...\right)$$

Comment: Tip: use the powerful identity $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}(f(x)^{g(x)})=f(x)^{g(x)}(g'(x)\ln(f(x))+\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}g(x)))$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $|x^x|<1$, you can recognize the sequence as a geometric sequence to find its sum.  Then, differentiate the sum of the geometric series.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(x^x+x^{2x}+x^{3x}+\ldots+x^{nx}\right)=\frac{x^x}{1-x^x}=-1+\frac{1}{1-x^x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(-1+\frac{1}{1-x^x}\right)=\frac{x^x \left(\ln{(x)}+1\right)}{{\left(1-x^x\right)}^2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Havent you shown that:
$$f'_N(x)=\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=1}^Nx^{nx}=(1+\ln x)\sum_{n=1}^Nnx^{nx}$$
now you need to find $\lim_{N\to\infty}f'_N$ one nice way of viewing this is that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^Nx^{nx}=\sum_{n=1}^N (x^x)^n$$
and this is a geometric series which is equal to:
$$x^x\frac{1-x^{Nx}}{1-x^x},\,|x^x|<1$$

Comment: It turns out that if we only care about positive values of $x$ we can simplify this domain to $0<x<1$